# Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range appears when running macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I'm trying to create a simple Sales Data Collection for exercise. I keep running into the run-time error and here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim myFirstBlackRow As Long

Set myWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

With myWorksheet

myFirstBlackRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=x1Formulas, LookAt:=x1Part, SearchOrder:=x1ByRows, SearchDirection:=x1Previous).Row + 1

With .Cells(myFirstBlackRow, 1)
    Select Case True
        Case OptionButton1.Value
            .Value = "Iphone"
        Case OptionButton2.Value
            .Value = "Samsung"
        Case OptionButton4.Value
            .Value = "Oppo"
        Case OptionButton3.Value
            .Value = "Huawei"
    End Select
End With

.Cells(myFirstBlackRow, 2).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value

End With

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help in advance, thanks!

Comment: On which line do you get an error?

Comment: It would be helpful if you tell at which line your code stops with error 9. But for sure it is as the error message says, such object or index just does not exist.

Comment: It doesn't show at which line there was the error. However, DisplayName below has found that the error was on the "myFirstBlackRow = .Cells.Find" line. Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change all your "1" (ones) to "l" ("l"s)

```
    myFirstBlackRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
```

this is one of the many (really many) reasons to always put `Option Explicit` at the top of every module

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! Yes everything works now!

Comment: @AntiDrondert, that is quite common an issue. and you get that at "compile" time by putting `Option Explicit`